# Referenciar dos atributos de una tabla a una clave primaria de otra tabla

Tags: sql, oracle

qué tal les va?

Verán, estoy realizando un logbook para pilotos privados. Entre todas las entidades (tablas) resultantes, tengo dos: vuelo y aeropuerto. Esta tabla Aeropuerto, se compone de : ID, Código OACI, Nombre y la FK de la ciudad.

Entre los campos de la tabla Vuelo hay dos en especial: Aeropuerto_Salida y Aeropuerto_Llegada. También hay una FK de la tabla aeropuerto.

Sin embargo, ¿cómo puedo estructurar la base de datos para no tener que, por ejemplo, hacer dos tablas adicionales: Aeropuerto_Llegada y Aeropuerto_Salida (ambos contendrían exactamente los mismos datos, por lo que lo veo redundante)?.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Saludos!

[image: El modelo relacional. Nótese las tablas Vuelo y Aeropuerto.]

Comment: Este es el problema de querer utilizar la base de datos para solucionar problemas de negocios. No, no debes relacionar la tabla vuelos con ninguna tabla, de eso se tiene que encargar tu capa de negocios. Si quisieras hacerlo en BD, pq es un ejercicio teorico, deberias tener 2 tablas aeropuertos.

Comment: ¿Por qué tendrías que requerir de dos tablas? La tabla 'Aeropuerto' es base de referencia para las columnas 'Aeropuerto_Salida' y 'Aeropuerto_Llegada', ambas columnas deberían tener la restricción FK "señalando" a la misma tabla: 'Aeropuerto'.

Answer (score -1):

Recuerda que los FK hacen referencia a una tabla externa para validar que el dato que se ingrese en ese campo exista en la otra tabla, con la opción de aceptar o no Nulos.

Lo que tienes que tener es dos FK uno para el campo `Aeropuerto_Salida` y otro para `Aeropuerto_Llegada`, ambos haciendo referencia al campo de la tabla `Aeropuertos`.

Te recomiendo que tus referencias siempre sean llaves primarias y con las opciones de `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT`, lo que te permite actualizar tus referencias y bloquear la eliminacion de registros referenciados.

Comment: Hola Miguel, se agradece tu colaboración, pero te sugiero revises [answer] es muy importante, esto para que sepas como debe realizarse 
una respuesta.  Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar, saludos!.